# Bootstrap responsive table does not scroll correctly on iOS, works fine on Android

Tags: android, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website has a responsive table for the shopping cart.  On Android, it works fine...the left half of the cart is shown, and when swiped, a horizontal scroll bar briefly appears, and the table shifts and displays the right half.

On an iPhone 6, the left half of the table seems to bleed over the borders of the screen so it looks ugly.  When swiped, the grey scroll bar also appears, but the screen barely moves and then springs back to showing only the left half.  Holding my finger on the screen I can get about 50% of the right half to appear, before it snaps back when my finger reaches the edge of the screen.

I looked at previous similar questions, and tried the solutions I could see, but none made a difference.  I tried:

```
overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

I tried:

```
.table-responsive .table {
max-width: none;
}
```

I tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

on my master page.

I made changes in my CSS files, the bootstrap.css and the bootstrap.min.css files.

The HTML code for the tables is pretty simple:

```
<div data-bind='if: Items().length' class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table  outside-border">
                            <thead>
                                <tr style="background-color: #eee;">
                                    <th>Prod #</th>
                                    <th>Qty</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                                    <th class="text-right">Total</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr class="double-top-border">
                                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right ">Subtotal:
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2" class="text-bold text-right">
                                        <span data-bind="text: '$' + SubTotal().toFixed(2)"></span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
....
```

---

Here are screenshots.  The first two are the iPhone, the second two the Android:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

So, basically, I need help in making the iPhone site work in the way the site does on Android, with tables being divided cleanly on the screen without the chopped up borders and overlaps, for the tables to be fully scrollable, and for the table to stay in the right half when scrolled and not bounce back.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you provide live URL if you have one?

Comment: Unfortunately you would have to be a registered customer to see the cart pages, this is not a retail site.  But the URL is https://www.brooksequipment.com

Comment: I was hoping someone else had seen this issue before, but I guess there is some combination of things I am doing that is causing this on iPhones but nowhere else.  I have had to make very simple, ugly (in my opinion) tables just so it looks okay on iPhones.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem is in horizontal scrolling...

use inline css to div :

```
style="overflow-x:scroll"

<div data-bind='if: Items().length' class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x:scroll">
```

If this works then use it on particular class if you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, but this did not make any difference that I could see.